# How can I use vector of an abstract/interface class as function parameter?

Tags: c++, vector, arguments, c++17, abstract-class

I'm trying to use a vector of an abstract/interface class `Base` as parameter to a function `g` (in `main.cpp`), so that i can pass vectors of derived classes as arguments.

Since I can't have instances of `Base`, I'm trying to pass vectors of unique pointers instead -- as this seems to be the preferred way to do it. However, I'm not allowed to convert from `vector<unique_ptr<Test::A>>` to `vector<unique_ptr<Test::Base>>` for some reason and I don't understand why.

**Question: why is this not allowed and how can I solve it?**

`module.hpp` looks like this:

```
#ifndef _MODULE_HPP
#define _MODULE_HPP

namespace Test
{
    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Base(){};

        virtual int f(int a, int b) = 0;
    };

    class A : public Base
    {
    public:
        A();
        ~A() = default;

        int f(int a, int b);
    };
}

#endif
```

`module.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <module/module.hpp>

Test::A::A() {}

int Test::A::f(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
};
```

`main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <module/module.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

void g(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::Base>> v)
{
    for (std::unique_ptr<Test::Base> &vi : v)
    {
        std::cout << vi->f(1, 2) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::A>> v;

    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test::A>());
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test::A>());

    g(v);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra  -I src -I include -c -o build/module/module.o src/module/module.cpp
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra  -I src -I include -c -o build/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
src/main.cpp:26:4: error: could not convert ‘v’ from ‘vector<unique_ptr<Test::A>>’ to ‘vector<unique_ptr<Test::Base>>’
   26 |  g(v);
      |    ^
      |    |
      |    vector<unique_ptr<Test::A>>
make: *** [Makefile:36: build/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you change `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::A>> v;` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::Base>> v;` ? As `std::unique_ptr<Test::A>` is not related to `std::unique_ptr<Test::Base>` so there can be no conversion(s).

Comment: @RicharCritten `std::unique_ptr` has such conversions but `std::vector` not

Comment: @RichardCritten That gives me the error `static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I can't the conversion to mention to work - live - https://godbolt.org/z/rd5hcn39c

Comment: @RichardCritten thats because you are trying to make copies. https://godbolt.org/z/91zYz8raf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Derived>>` are not [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), and no conversion function between them exists, so you cannot simply treat one as the other.
They are completely different, unrelated types.

#### Polymorphic Storage

If you need polymorphic storage, why not just use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` everywhere?
You can insert `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` into it like this:

```cpp
// note: passing by reference to avoid having to move the vector
//       (copying would be illegal)
void g(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::Base>> &v)
{
    for (const std::unique_ptr<Test::Base> &vi : v)
    {
        std::cout << vi->f(1, 2) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test::Base>> v;

    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test::A>());
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test::A>());

    g(v);
}
```

#### Accepting Vectors of Covariant Types

Alternatively, if you just need to store a `std::vector<Derived>` but want to pass it into functions that take a range of `Base` values, you can do this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

// C++20 version using concepts
template <std::derived_from<Test::Base> Derived>
void g(std::vector<Derived> &v)
{
    for (Test::Base &vi : v)
    {
        std::cout << vi.f(1, 2) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// C++17 counterpart
template <typename Derived>
auto g(std::vector<Derived> &v)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Test::Base, Derived>>
{ ... }
```

To call `g`, we need to declare `std::vector<Test::A> v;` in `main`.
We could make this function even more generic if we used ranges, so we would no longer rely on `std::vector` specifically.

```cpp
// C++20 version
template <std::ranges::input_range Range>
requires (std::derived_from<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>, Test::Base>)
void g(Range &v)
{
    for (Test::Base &vi : v)
    {
        std::cout << vi.f(1, 2) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// C++17 version would be much more difficult because we lack the proper type traits.
// If we accepted two iterators, it would become easier.
template <typename ForwardIt>
auto g(ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Test::Base, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type>>
{ ... }

// call this function like g(v.begin(), v.end())
```

*Note: You could also leave the templates unconstrained, which would make this easier to implement in C++17.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My aim is not to have polymorphic storage, but rather to have arguments to `g` restricted to vectors of `Base` derivatives. Given what I've learned today I'm assuming that it's better to use templates to achieve this, e.g.: `template <class T> void h(std::vector<T> &v)`. It would be nice if C++ had something like `template <class T extends Test::Base>` like in Java to be more explicit about intent, though.

Comment: @Max C++ has that and much more :D [`std::derived_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from)

Comment: @Max I've edited my question with an explanation of how to do that. I seriously recommend C++20 for this though, if possible.

Comment: @JanSchultke Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for. Appreciated!